# How to combine confusion matrices from the outputs of multiple algorithms?

Tags: join, r-caret, confusion-matrix, rbind, cbind

I want to extract prediction confusion matrices of multiple prediction models in one table for easier comparison.
I collected confusion matrix tables from each model and combined them to created the following table.

```
Table1 <- rbind(confmat_nb$table, confmat_nb_2$table, confmat_svm$table)                          
Table1

      

                      Reference
                            excluded    included
      naive_bayes   excluded    6234    46
                    included    3107    470
      naive_bayes_2 excluded    5774    60
                    included    3567    456
      svm           excluded    7197    101
                    included    2144    415
```

Table 2 was created using the following code

```
byClass <- rbind(naive_bayes =round(confmat_nb$byClass, 3), 
                 naive_bayes_2=round(confmat_nb_2$byClass, 3),
                 svm = round(confmat_svm$byClass, 3)

overall <- rbind(naive_bayes =round(confmat_nb$overall, 3), 
                 naive_bayes_2=round(confmat_nb_2$overall, 3),
                 svm = round(confmat_svm$overall, 3)

Table2 <- rbind(byClass, overall)

Table2

             Accuracy   Sensitivity Specificity Pos Pred Value  Neg Pred Value  Precision   
  naive_bayes   0.680     0.911      0.667        0.131            0.993        0.131   
  naive_bayes_2 0.632     0.884      0.618        0.113            0.990        0.113   
  svm           0.772     0.804      0.770        0.162            0.986        0.162
```

My goal is to merge Table 1 and Table 2 and extract the outputs in one table. Something like this
[image]